# Best approximation of vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, orthogonality

Consider the inner product space $P([0,1])$ of all real polynomials on $[0,1]$ with inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$ and $V=span\{t^2\}$.
Let  $h(t) \in V$ be such that $\|(2t-1)-h(t)\| \le \|(2t-1)-x(t)\|$ for $x(t) \in V$, then $h(t)$ is

$$a ) \frac{5t^2}{6}$$
$$b ) \frac{5t^2}{3}$$

This is my thought. Since $2t-1-h(t)$ is orthogonal to $V$ therefore $a$ must be the correct answer but in the book $b$ is given as correct answer.

Comment: OK. I've fixed your latex 3 times, and each time you re-edit and mess it up. How 'bout looking at what I did before you destroy it?

Comment: Sorry actually I am using it in mobile therefore I am having problem Could you please fix it?

Comment: Done. I'm pretty sure that's the correct version of your question. Now...why do you think that $2t - 1 - h(t)$ is orthogonal to $V$?

Comment: Because by best approximation theorem $ 2t-1-h(t) $ must be orthogonal to V. So only $a$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: @john hughes by orthogonal decomposition theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I did the integral correctly, I agree that the dot product of $q(t) = 2t -1 - h(t) $ (for the function $h$ given in answer "a") and $r(t) = t^2$ is indeed $0$, so the answer should be "a" rather than "b".

Comment: Is my argument correct? Can I apply orthogonal decomposition theorem? Or Best approximation theorem?